# Make an Excel COM add-in a VSTO add-in

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-addins, comaddin

I have coded an Excel add-in using Visual C#. This add-in appears as a COM add-in in Excel. However, I am quite sure that it used to appear as an Excel/VSTO Add-In in Excel before an update of Visual Studio. (I know that I was able to access the Globals class. [This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/13236b1e-0eab-4ee5-8bc9-a53d8953ab5b/problems-creating-an-excel-addin-with-vsto?forum=vsto) says that Globals can only be accessed in Excel add-ins.)

So my question is: How can I make my COM add-in an Excel/VSTO add-in?

Comment: Where are you looking in Excel? Can you show us a screen shot? For example, the COM Add-ins dialog box in the Developer tab doesn't differentiate between VSTO and other kinds of COM Add-in. Note that a VSTO add-in is also a COM Add-in - it bases on the IDTExtensibility2 interface, just as every COM add-in does. Microsoft simply made it easier to create the COM add-in and included some extensions (such as bindings and the Ribbon designer).

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Office project, Visual Studio automatically generates a class named `Globals` in the project. You can use the `Globals` class to access several different project items at run time from any code in the project.

You can start writing your VSTO Add-in code in the `ThisAddIn` class. Visual Studio automatically generates this class in the `ThisAddIn.vb` (in Visual Basic) or `ThisAddIn.cs` (in C#) code file in your VSTO Add-in project. The Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime automatically instantiates this class for you when the Microsoft Office application loads your VSTO Add-in. Read more about that in the [Program VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) article.

Also, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.... thats COM... **Interop**erability. VSTO is a COM.